AT25SF081 SPI Flash FPGA issue narrow
From my previous post, I think I understand correctly the electronics side of the Read Manufacturer and Device ID Signal (Figure 11-1) Operation.
My current implementation of the operation on the FPGA does not return the expected response on the SO line - there is a discrepancy:
Instead of the expected response:

hex: 1F, 85, 01,

I am seeing:

hex: 00, 00, 00.

So now I want to narrow down the cause of this issue.
My hypothesis is that it is likely an issue with the Verilog implementation of the operation, as the issue seems unlikely to be a fault at the physical layer.
Why? Because the FPGA configuration is loaded to/from the first three 64kb of flash memory, and when I try compiling and uploading the customer example configs, the FPGA works well (buttons/leds are responding as expected). This suggests that the Flash and FPGA are at least able to communicate via SPI in some way, as the FPGA must be using SPI to set its configuration data from the flash.
I.e. the flash is working to do re-configurations on the FPGA, but not to do the operation above - and so it seems that it should be a verilog issue on the software side rather than a hardware issue at the physical layer.
Would I then be correct in deducing from these facts that only thing that could cause this response discrepancy is the Verilog implementation of the operation, and not the physical hardware of the device?

These 2 observations seem to contradict each other:

"the FPGA does not return the expected response on the SO line"
"the Flash and FPGA are at least able to communicate via SPI."

When you say "communicate via SPI", I presume you confirmed that the FPGA successfully read some bytes via the SPI.
I don't think the evidence you have posted in the question necessarily points to a Verilog problem.  There could be other issues elsewhere in your system.
If you suspect the Verilog design, try to create a simulation testbench with a scenario that mimics the sequence you are running in hardware, up to the point where you read the Flash ID bytes.
When you program the FPGA from your Verilog code, you probably get a bunch of report files.  If so, read all the reports, looking for any warning messages or anything else that looks unexpected.
Observe actual waveforms of your FPGA SPI pins using some form of measuring equipment.  If you see the 1F, 85, 01 byte sequence, then that could point to a Verilog/FPGA problem.

Ah I see, I have updated the question to try and explain further these observations

I have not confirmed yet that the FPGA has read any bytes via SPI

So I have in fact created this testbench for mimic-ing already! But not no avail, it seems

In terms of the measuring equipment, what would you suggest to use for this?

@K_T: Whatever equipment you have available (scope, logic analyzer, etc.).  If you are new to all of this, then welcome to the wonderful world of debugging!  It is the best (if not most painful) way to learn.

I see, thanks! What oscilloscope should I get for this?

@K_T: You're welcome.  I'm not sure what type of equipment would be best for your setup.
